# Need efficient way to solve this with Linq/subsonic

Tags: linq, subsonic

I have a table Sentences that has an ID and Sentence column. This is a fairly large table, +- 100000 rows. I am given a list of words and I need to find the sentences that contains these words. The resultant sentences must be unique.

```
_session.All<Sentence>()
        .Select(T => new { ID = T.ID, Sentences = T.sentence.Split(' ') })
        .Where(S => S.Sentences.Intersect(Words).Count()>0)
        .Select(R=>R.ID)
```

from here it's pretty simple but this seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.Count()>0` you should use `.Any()`.

Also, it does not appear as though you are doing anything to get unique sentences, like use a `.Distinct()` at the end.

Maybe like this:

```
_session.All<Sentence>()
        .Select(T => new { ID = T.ID, Sentences = T.sentence.Split(' ') })
        .Where(S => S.Sentences.Intersect(Words).Any())
        .Select(R=>R.ID)
        .Distinct() // may not be necessary
```

Comment: this is just a start that I'm not happy to finish because there has to be a better solution than this. Splitting 100 000 sentences into words is scary. This cannot be the only possible solution.

Comment: Splitting the sentences into words is almost certainly going to be the most efficient way to do it. Looking for words within complete sentences isn't going to be any faster.

Comment: _session.All<Sentence>().Select(T => new { Sentence = T, Descriptions = T.Sentence.Split(' ') }).Where(S => S.Sentence.Intersect(words).Any()).Select(R => R.Sentence).Distinct()  not working I'm getting The expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]' is not a sequence